# Silently install voices for a ttsEngine extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, text-to-speech

I'm creating a speech extension for my webpage in order to make it accessible for blind people. This works good so far, now I wanted to have the two voice engines I picked installed automatically. And this has proven to be really difficult:
I've been through tons of info on how to approach this. The easiest way would be to just open the voice (ttsEngine)'s web page in the Chrome store - but then the blind people would have to go through all this hassle as well.
Most other approaches require computer permissions I do not have, e.g. messing with the user's file system or registry.

My question: Is there really no easy way to require, include or preinstall another extension for your extension, so it installs in the background (silently)?

Thanks for hearing me out and providing some help!
Kind regards,
Roman

Comment: Do I have to use NPAPI? I know that's a way, but if there's a way around it for simply installing voices I'd very much prefer that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also posted this issue in [google groups's Chromium-extensions](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-extensions/eRiokHydX9o/hdRlMpEW0VwJ), there the result was that such a thing is not (yet?) possible with extensions only.

It is true that if they were open source I could maybe include them into my project, yet these are not.
For now it seems I have to either do it with "management" like suggested in the link or create an installable that messes with the Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permission to modify / extend / redistribute the other extensions?  they could probably be merged into a single extension with your code, if for example they are open source.